# How can i change my Var to Float in GUI Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

```
private void btnCalculateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    var input1String = txtInput1.getText().trim();
    var input1 = Integer.parseInt(input1String);

    var input2String = txtInput2.getText().trim();
    var input2 = Integer.parseInt(input2String);

    var result = (input1/input2)/input2;
    var resultString = String.valueOf(result);
    txtOutput.setText(resultString);
```

how can i change my var to float so i can get decimal like 0,212 etc

Comment: If this even was java you could just write float num = Float.parseFloat(txtInput.getText()); or cast as a float depending on the situation

Comment: @Hensel why are you using the var keyword

Comment: @faris im a newbie in java, it is an syllabus in my college, im used to code in python, and thankyou for ur help faris

Comment: I don't understand how you have all of the other (more complex) code in java somewhat correctly but you messed up the variable declarations which is like step 1 of learning the language at all

Comment: @Arek ill look it up, thank you so much Arek, this is the first time im asking a question in StackOverflow, and the people are really helpful

Comment: @faris believe i also dont know how the code work out, but i have been studying python and SQL for a year now, and when i got introduced to java i went immediately blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
float input1String = txtInput1.getText() == null ? 0.0f : Float.valueOf(txtInput1.getText().trim());
```

which can throw an exception if the value of yout Textfiled is not a float value

Comment: oh my god thank you so much, i have been trying to figuring this out for hours and the deadline is tonight

Comment: @Hensel if it helps, feel free to accept and/or upvote These answer

Comment: IT WORKED OUT THANK YOU SO MUCHH

Comment: @Hensel Since this answer appeared to solve your problem could you please upvote it and/or accept the answer. This will help others in the community who may have a similar problem.